# how to find out if product is existed, if yes + value of number

Tags: php, shopping-cart

I´m looking for some help about my shopping cart. I use a simple script. Everything works as I want, but I don´t know how to find out if some products already exist, if they do I want to increment the value. The script is below:

```
for ($x=0;$x<count( $_SESSION["sess_name"]);$x++) {
    $x_id= $_SESSION["sess_id"];
    $x_name_prd= $_SESSION["sess_name_prd"];
    $x_number_prd= $_SESSION["sess_number_prd"];

   //if there is a product that is already in the cart then go to function check_me(); to do something to make the sess_number_prd +1 everytimes people click on the button.
    if ( $x_name_prd[$x]==$name_prd){
        check_me($x_name_prd[$x]);
    }
}
```

**I have tried this method, but does not work**

```
function check_me ($name_prd)  {
    for ($i=0;$i<count($_SESSION['sess_name']);$i++) {
        if (!in_array($_SESSION['sess_id'][$i],$)) {
            $temp_id[]=$_SESSION['sess_id'][$i];
            $temp_name[]=$_SESSION['sess_name_prd'][$i];

            $temp_num[]=+1;
        }
    }
    $_SESSION['sess_id']=$temp_id;
    $_SESSION['number_prd']=+1;
    $_SESSION['sess_name']=$temp_name;
}
```

Can someone help me please..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you've some control over the structure of the array stored in $_SESSION for your basket I'd recommend using something like this.

```
/*Entry point
  It is assumed at this point you have the value product id ($pid) and initiated 
  your $_SEESION[<basket array index>] set - "basket" in this example
*/
(isset($_SESSION['basket'][$pid]))? $_SESSSION['basket'][$pid]++ : $_SESSION['basket'][$pid] = 1;
```

This approach doesn't require the iterative comparison of each item in the basket to determine if an instance of it has already been added to the basket. This will allow for a simple

```
foreach($_SESSION['basket'] as $product_id => $noOfProduct){
     /*Do your checkout thing here*/
}
```

to process the basket once you're finished adding to it.

**Code posted in the comments by Alex, example of the problem not a solution**

```
for ($x=0;$x<count( $_SESSION["sess_id"]);$x++){
    $x_id= $_SESSION["sess_id"][$x];    //[$x] appended, presumed missing
    $x_id_prd= $_SESSION["sess_id_prd"];
    $x_name_prd= $_SESSION["sess_name"]; 
    $x_size_prd= $_SESSION["sess_size"]; 
    $x_color_prd= $_SESSION["sess_color"];
    $x_clr_code_prd= $_SESSION["sess_clr_code"]; 
    $x_num_prd= $_SESSION["sess_num"]; 
    if($x_id_prd[$x]==$id_prd 
      && $x_size_prd[$x]==$size_prd 
      && $x_color_prd[$x]==$color_prd 
      && $x_clr_code_prd[$x]==$clr_code ){ 
        //do something to get $_SESSION["sess_num"]+1;
    } 
}
```

**End of comment code**

Comment: I don´t think this work for me, Because I have another methode to generrate the $pid...and everything work good. ( The reason is I have many choices in one product: size, color etc.) I can also find out which product is already exist in cookie, But I don´t know how to make it +1 in the corect pars. Seemed like the script don´t know where to put..:S

Comment: here is some code :

for ($x=0;$x<count( $_SESSION["sess_id"]);$x++) {
 
   $x_id= $_SESSION["sess_id"];
   $x_id_prd= $_SESSION["sess_id_prd"];
   $x_name_prd= $_SESSION["sess_name"];
   $x_size_prd= $_SESSION["sess_size"];
   $x_color_prd= $_SESSION["sess_color"];
   $x_clr_code_prd= $_SESSION["sess_clr_code"];
   $x_num_prd= $_SESSION["sess_num"];
   

   
   if ( $x_id_prd[$x]==$id_prd and $x_size_prd[$x]==$size_prd and $x_color_prd[$x]==$color_prd and $x_clr_code_prd[$x]==$clr_code ) {
 
do something to get $_SESSION["sess_num"]+1;

   
    }
 
 
  }

Comment: Right I've put your code in the comments which should make this easier. You were missing [$x] from the first line within the for loop. I think you're trying to access session members which are either embedded within the sess_id sub array(if it exists) or you need to append [$x] to each of your $_SESSION vars within your for loop.

Comment: Yeah looks good now, but how to get  $_SESSION["sess_num"]+1;?
This is the problem...:S

Comment: Would $_SESSION['sess_num']++ not d the trick? Again I think you're missing [$x] from each but apart from that the aforementioned line of code should do the trick.

Comment: Just now it seemed like I can plus the $sess_num, but the other record n cookie was deleted...seemd like it does not understand which one need to be update.

Comment: Could you provide the sess_* Array structure in your question? I think that'll help solve the problem. One line to look at is your if($x_id_prd[$x]... When you declare $x_id_prd you're not declaring setting a single value and reading it as an array, if it is an array then consider replacing the array structure with something that binds product details to a single array within an array of all products in the session.

Comment: I found the solution now. yezzzz!
I use your last updated and then put $_SESSION['sess_num'][$x]++ ;
$check=2;

I really don´t know why the $check=2 is helps.....very strange...I don´t have any function with the $check=2 at all. but If u take it out, i got wrong script...can u explain me ? I tried to use return false in stead, but did not work....

although I found the solution, I please explain me.

Comment: No worries; if you post your working code into your question, separate it from the initial of course and I'll have a look at it. Also if you have the site privilege to use the chat I'm here for a while and that might spare the comment thread.

Comment: ... what made you think to add $check = 2?

Comment: So sad, i don´t have enaugh privilege to chat. What made I putted $check haha look here:



if (count($_SESSION['sess_id'])=="0") {
 $check=1;
} else  if (!in_array($id_prd, $_SESSION['sess_id'])) {
 $check=1;
}
BUT $check=2 supposed to be a choice which I will do something if there are the same product ( that was the plan) But in the end i have got yor script and it did not work properly as i said until i puted $check=2; so strange. ALthough I have test it and it work fine, but I want to know why...I fear the wrong thing that may happen in the future.